# 2012 Pathfinder won't remember radio station or daylight savings setting

Tags: nissan, audio, pathfinder

My wife's 2012 Pathfinder Silver Edition doesn't remember the radio station or daylight saving setting the majority of the time.  This [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Nissan/comments/2jdovq/help_please_my_father_has_a_2011_pathfinder_and/) outlines our issue, but the solutions there haven't helped us.

To be clear, the 18 presets are retained day to day, but the one that was being listened to previously is not.  About 90% of the time, the daylight savings setting and radio station (or CD track, etc) is forgotten the next trip.  Maybe 10% of the time it will actually remember the settings and use those for the next 8-10 trips until the next random time it decides to save our clock/radio settings when shutting off the car.  It is very frustrating to fight the clock every 6 months when DST starts and ends.

The radio is out of warranty so I'm hesitant to take it to the dealer because I assume they will just start swapping boxes and charge us $1000 each time to fix such a simple thing.  We have two key FOBs and I've replaced the batteries with between zero and minimal change.

So my question is where is the daylight savings and radio settings stored?  Is it in the radio itself or in the key FOB or somewhere else?  It would be fairly simple for someone with a Pathfinder and two key FOBS to test.

From a software/electronics standpoint, it doesn't make sense to me that the DST setting would be stored in the key, but it does make sense to store radio settings in the key.

Update Aug 2019 - The problem got worse.  Have been unable get the DST setting to keep since it changed in March this year.  Very frustrating.  I finally resorted to figuring out how to get it set by disconnecting the battery.  One might guess that the radio would default to 12:00 after it lost power, but it does not!  After disconnecting it several times for several hours each time, it seemed to reliably start at 4:00 each time.  So it is 4:10 in the afternoon and 10 minutes ago I just re-attached the battery cable and the clock is showing the correct time for the first time since March!  Just wanted others to know an alternate way to set the clock, if Email's solution doesn't work for you (it never did for me, but appears it worked for others).

Comment: These steps worked on my 2012 Pathfinder as well. Thanks it was driving me nuts. Also a SW engineer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is only an id and password rolled up in one place. Never assume anything is stored in a key. This isnt a feasable tech solution.

The radio holds those values when changed.

Problem introduction:
I had a similar issue with my radio where i would save a new radio preset value or clock setting and when i returned to use the truck again... those presets that had been available/saved in the previous use session reverted back to presets I had seen before. These old presets are not factory defaults. They are other presets i was able to slip into the radio system over time of a preset sticking... here and there.

Dealer interaction and opinion:
I did call and then take my truck to the dealer for other service. I opened discussion with the not so well informed service writer asking to confirm there is/isnt new software updates... After hooking to the computer... confirmed i am up to date as to what should be
He then informed me/ opinionated that my radio needs replacing. Ya ya... i think not. It really is a software issue.

I didnt bite. Neither should you.

My problem described:
My presets would save until i restarted the truck.. at starter turnover... i would loose the preset values just input and saved. My preset values would go back to previous saved settings.

Please note i also see a difference in one intelligent key equals a group of radio/clock presets that differ from the other intelligent key and its radio/clock presets.

Relative other issues:
I do believe this also affects stored values like the service mileage alarms and miles per gallon read outs.

Clarifying thoughts:
I am a software developer by trade and approached my problem with software testing practises... always noting carefully everytime my saved setting changed... and asking what my recent radio interactions had been.

It took me a total of 8 months in which to bump into my solution for my 2010 nissan armada radio/no nav experiments to payoff. Please note i only performed a test when using the truck and radio for any daily trip or errand hence the 8 months to solution.

Subnote:
If your presets change on their own to new and totally random values every xx to many uses... i dont think we truely have the same issue. I do think you should try and log specific actions to activate your entire onboard computer. Do try the solution step choices below... one at a time... then all three

If you want to solve the software issues so you can understand the programming bug to work around... you are going to have to be scientific and exact in your recall of test and usage practices. ie: ya cant be a dummy about it.

Suggested testing practises:
I have engaged trip,tire,settings clock and all other menu items and potential button pushes as my internal changes saved testing process.

Money shot/ SOLUTION:
My solution was to change channels and store the memory stations i wish to keep.... then...

1. Turn radio off on off on many times.
2. Put the truck in reverse with the camera showing change a radio station or turn itnoff.
3. Lock and unluck the truck with the remote many times.

*
The random, save event doesnt always happen.... so when in doubt please try this set of actions more than once in order to see results.

**
Fyi, the actual test to see if your changes sticknis to turn off the vehicle, open door and exit... lock with remote or button push on door handle and walk out of range for the rfid to be sensed by the vehicle.
Then return and restart vehicle.

DISCLAIMER:
I know these steps are odd and certainly not  book solution items... but my correct clock and radio preset values are the ones i have input and intentionally saved. These steps have solved my radio issues in my 2010 Nissan Armada... non navigation.

Hi,
Its been a year since i have been here to view my comments.

I am glad to see i have helped a few readers get past the annoyance of nissan radios. :)

The add to my statements above.... i have continued to see random save events to the radio settings... which seem to be triggered mostly by a reverse and radio power off action.

Example.

I back out of the garage... kids are talking and the radio volume is up... i turn off the radio, engage in the kids conversation... finish backing the truck and drive away.

I start the radio at my conveinience and drive home and park etc.

At next start my radio is turned off and stays that way till my next random save event.

Best of luck to all readers. I get it my grammer osnt always perfect.  Wordy but not perfect. Haha

Comment: Thank you so much! Those simple instructions worked! 2010 Nissan Murano clock would not hold time after reset and turning the car off, then back on. Look here!!!

Comment: This solved my clock problem in my 2011 Pathfinder! Thank you so much! This has been irritating me for months!!! 